# Shift the value to the right in Excel when opening the csv file

Tags: java, excel, csv

I am trying to shirt the values with leading zero to the right when opening the csv file with Excel MS. I am using `bufferedWriter.write("\\"\t"+row[4] + "\\"\t");` . The tabe and quote to display the leading zero since without it I am just getting `46` and not `046`.

```
    if(row[4].startsWith("0")){
            bufferedWriter.write(";" + "\\"\t"+row[4] + "\\"\t");
        }else{
         bufferedWriter.write(";" + row[4]);
        }
```

**screen shot**

[image]

Comment: There are extra "\" characters in this line: bufferedWriter.write(";" + "\\"\t"+row[4] + "\\"\t");  Is this line supposed to be: bufferedWriter.write(";" + "\"\t"+row[4] + "\"\t");

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. Fix the write line to properly escape the quote

   bufferedWriter.write(";" + "\"\t"+row[4] + "\"\t");

This is the output (I am using the pipe/"|" instead of a new line)

```
2016;"  046"    |2016;" 046"    |2016;400|2016;400|
```

2. Remove the second tab to get rid of the extra space in your display

   bufferedWriter.write(";" + "\"\t"+row[4]);

This is now the output

```
2016;"  046"|2016;" 046"|2016;400|2016;400|
```